# I remove element on purpose but it does not show up as undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to test to see if I can have a function to dynamically add an element along with its ID via Jquery if it is missing in HTML, but it does not show up as null or undefined, so I can't get it to create itself.

HTML

```
<div id="player">
     <p>Player</p>
     <!--<p id="pName"></p>-->
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function CCPlayer (player) {
  switch (player) {
    case 'Name': {
      if ('#pName' == undefined) {
        alert('1')
        $('#player').prepend('<p id="pName"></p>')
      } else if ('#pName' == null) {
        alert('2')
        $('#pName').html('<p>Name: ' + pn + '</p>')
      }
    } break

CCPlayer('Name')
```

The one that shows null is supposed to be != in order for alert 2 to show up when an element is already present, but alert 1 does not show up, so I mark it as undefined and null in both scenario, but no alert shows up when an element is not present in HTML, so that means when it checks for missing element, it somehow is not null neither undefined as I was expecting it to be. So, what am I suppose to put down to search for a missing element, and if it not there, return an alert that it not there.

Comment: You are missing $

Comment: Nothing happens.

if ($('#pName') == undefined) {
        alert('1')
        $('#player').prepend('<p id="pName"></p>')
      }

dave solve my issue, apparently undefined and null does not work on my "string".

Comment: See answer from #dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the string `'#pName'` is `undefined` or `null` - it never will be.  I think you want to do:

```
if ($('#pName').length === 0) {
    //...
} else if ($('#pName').html().length === 0) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This one work. But can I ask why it wont pass as null nor undefined if the element that contains the only ID of pName is missing? Also what is ===, I understand that = is assigning value to something, and == is one of those comparison operators. but I never heard of ===.

Also, you say string, but is it not an ID of an element?

Comment: It is a string which happens to contain the ID of an element.  But it's not the element itself, just a string.  You can't check if it's null or undefined because `$('#pName')` doesn't return null if it doesn't exist, and it doesn't return undefined if it doesn't exist.  It returns a jQuery object.  They do this so that you can do something like `$('#pName').hide()` and it won't crash if `#pName` doesn't exist, it just won't do anything.

Comment: Is there a way to search for a specific element then? I am fine with this method if there no way to search for a specific element.